# Find the particular solution for $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=4xe^{-x}\cos(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=4xe^{-x}\cos(x)$

I'm having trouble finding the particular solution, but so far I found the general solution by first obtaining the characteristic equation:

$r^2+2r+2=0$

And after using the quadratic formula to factor it, I got:

$-1+i$

Which means the general solution is:

$y=c_1e^{-x}\cos(x)+c_2e^{-x}\sin(x)$

$y'=c_2e^{-x}\cos(x)-c_1e^{-x}\sin(x)-c_2e^{-x}\sin(x)-c_1e^{-x}\cos(x)$

From here I know I can write the particular solution, but I'm not sure how to do it given the form of $y$ and $y'$

Comment: Did you want to use Undetermined Coefficients, Variation of Parameters or Laplace transforms or Guessing?

Comment: @Moo undetermined coefficients

Comment: First, the roots were $m_{1, 2} = -1 \pm i$, but you only needed one to write the homogeneous solution. Since your homogeneous solution contains $e^{-x} \cos x$, you would multiply your particular solution by $x$, so choose $y_p(x) = x~ e^{-x}~(a~ \cos x + b~ \sin x + c~ x \cos x + d~ x \sin x)$.

Comment: @Moo wow, that actually makes so much sense to me.  I was really close.

Comment: Great - the algebra for that $y_p(x)$ is a bit messy, but excellent work! I think you will find $a = 1, b = 0, c = 0, d = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters